# Why truffle compile does not compile anything?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLahq4qyors&t=485s and I cannot compile anything. There is literally no output and message says `> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.`

The truffle-config.js:

```
require('babel-register');
require('babel-polyfill');

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
  },
  contracts_directory: './src/contracts/',
  contracts_build_directory: './src/abis/',
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      },
      evmVersion: "petersburg"
    }
  }
}
```

The TokenFarm contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract TokenFarm {
    string private _name = "DApp Token Farm";
    string private _symbol = "dATF";

    function name() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }
}
```

And the 2_deploy_contracts.js:

```
const TokenFarm = artifacts.require('TokenFarm');

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(TokenFarm);
}
```

The overall structure of the project:
[image: The overall structure of the project]

Comment: use sudo if you're on Linux eg. sudo truffle compile

Answer (score -2):

you need to add the network ID to connect to ganache

Comment: I think this owuld help if you write a code example of what you mean.